# How to create thumbnail images in a table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have several images that I want to show in a table but in a thumbnail version. Something like this:

[image: Click to open the example image]

In the image above, you can see that images has different sizes, some are higher than others, that's what I'm trying to do, 
small images but retaining its orientation format.

This is my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Images</title>
</head>
<body>

<table>
 <thead>
  <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
   <th style="border: 1px solid black;">IMAGE</th>
   <th style="border: 1px solid black;">IMAGE</th>
   <th style="border: 1px solid black;">IMAGE</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>

 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="width: 200px !important; height: 200px !important; border: 1px solid black;"><div style="width: auto; height: auto;"><img src='https://i.ibb.co/6DsDQQ3/logo.png' width="50%" height="100%" style="margin-left: 50px;"></div></td>

   <td style="width: 200px !important; height: 200px !important; border: 1px solid black;"><div style="width: auto; height: auto;"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/0n2zfJg/product-features.png" width="50%" height="100%" style="margin-left: 50px;"></div></td>

   <td style="width: 200px !important; height: 200px !important; border: 1px solid black;"><div style="width: auto; height: auto;"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/6BRPLvs/intro-bg.jpg" width="50%" height="100%" style="margin-left: 50px;"></div></td>

  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I get thumbnail images?

UPDATE:
Another Example Image: 
[Another Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qa5or.png)
.This capture shows some images which are in a folder in my laptop, as you see, the image number 4 is highest than the others that's because the original image is highest than others. That's exactly what I want, show images smaller but respecting this kind of thing.

Comment: Could clarify whether you want the width or the height to be same between each thumbnail image? Also, are you wanting each image to be displayed on the baseline of the table cells?

Comment: do you want to use the <table> approach or can you use a responsive CSS approach (flexbox, for instance?)

Comment: In the example image that I have uploaded in the question you can see that there are some images, these are thumbnails of their original images. In these miniatures the images are like their originals, some are higher than others, that's what I want to achieve.

Comment: I have edited my question...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your code above your using 100% height and a fixed width.  Swap those properties. Give your images a fixed height and set width 100%.

```
.thumbnail img {
    height:250px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Install a whole front-end framework to use a thumbnail class?

Comment: @hungerstar the reason why front end frameworks and libraries exist is to make the developers life easier without having to write extra code yourself

Comment: I'm fully aware of why they exist and when they should be used. I simply do not think that adding a front end framework is a justifiable solution for this problem.

Comment: Actually I was trying to do something without using a framework, just only CSS.

Comment: @hungerstar   fair enough. I’ve edited my answer above. :)

Answer (score 0):

set just one property, choose to have all the images with the same height or the same width, for example for the same width:

```
  <tr>
            <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><img src='https://i.ibb.co/6DsDQQ3/logo.png'  style="height: 200px;"></td>

            <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/0n2zfJg/product-features.png"  style="height: 200px;"></td>

            <td style="border: 1px solid black;"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/6BRPLvs/intro-bg.jpg"  style="height: 200px;"></td>

        </tr>
```

btw, this will not change the loading time, if you want to reduce the loading time you need some backend language (PHP?) to return a smaller image on the fly.